# How to convert sqlalchemy dialect specific column type to another dialect?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, type-conversion

I would like to read table's metadata from one DB and create it another DB using Python & SQL Alchemy. It works perfectly if source and destination DBs are of the same type/dialect. But when I'm trying to replicate a table from MySQL DB to Oracle DB i'm experiencing problems with incompatible data types. For example in MySQL there are columns of SMALLINT / TINYINT / BIGINT / DATETIME data types, that don't exist in Oracle DB.

When I'm trying to convert one of those types using `.dialect_impl(ora_dialect)` i'm getting an `TypeError: 'memoized_property' object is not subscriptable` error.

Here is a small example:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import BIGINT
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import dialect as ora_dialect

i_mysql = BIGINT(20)

i_ora = i_mysql.dialect_impl(ora_dialect)
```

i'm getting the following error:

```
i_ora = i_mysql.dialect_impl(ora_dialect)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/umm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-135-998536c3e513>", line 1, in <module>
    i_ora = i_mysql.dialect_impl(ora_dialect)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/umm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 459, in dialect_impl
    return dialect._type_memos[self]["impl"]
TypeError: 'memoized_property' object is not subscriptable
```

What would be the right way to perform such a type conversion from one sqlalchemy dialect to another one?

PS here is the code that is used in order to get table's metadata:

```
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
meta.reflect(views=True, resolve_fks=False)

tab = meta.tables[table_name]
```

I've seen the parameter `meta.reflect(**dialect_kwargs)`, but I couldn't find any usage example...

Comment: If you think it's a XY-problem, then please let me know what would be the right approach.

Comment: You may be interested in the work being done in [this GitHub PR](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/pull/5714)